# How to init a WebElement with a wrapped element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have followed a tutorial on how to close random opened popups before doing any action :

https://www.vinsguru.com/selenium-webdriver-how-to-handle-annoying-random-popup-alerts/

The idea is to create an ElementProxy class which implements the interface `InvocationHandler`. so, the proxy’s invoke method would be called first before the actual method is invoked.

So we call `checkForPopupAndKill` before invoking any action on a WebElement.

Then we wrap our regular WebElement with this proxy object. We basically need a class which has a method to accept a WebElement and returns the WebElement with some wrapper.

In the tutorial they init elements of the page object with wrapper elements, like this:

```
//first init elements
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, pageobject);
        
        //then access all the WebElements and create a wrapper
        for(Field f:pageobject.getClass().getDeclaredFields()){
            if(f.getType().equals(WebElement.class)){
                boolean accessible = f.isAccessible();
                f.setAccessible(true);
                //reset the webelement with proxy object
                f.set(pageobject, ElementGuard.guard((WebElement) f.get(pageobject)));
                f.setAccessible(accessible);
            }  
        }
```

That's because they have declared fileds with the `@FindBy` annotation in the page object, but in my framework I'm declaring elements as following :

```
WebElement elt = getSmartElement(By.cssSelector("#my_id"));
```

My question is, how can I init my element with with the wrapper element ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the ElementGuard as shown here which wraps the actual WebElement with proxy.

`WebElement elt = ElementGuard.guard(getSmartElement(By.cssSelector("#my_id")));`